# How to read a property from the application.conf file in play framework?

Tags: java, playframework

I am a bit new to play framework. I am trying to get a property from the application.conf file to a controller class. Is there any way to do it?

Let's say we have defined a path as below in the application.conf

```
ProxyPass /testPath / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

So I need to get it to a controller class. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have added `cache.aerospike.namespace=1234` in your `application.conf`, you can access it in your controller like this:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

   String nameSpace = Play.application().configuration().getString("cache.aerospike.namespace");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inject an instance of `Config` to the controller:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import play.mvc.Controller;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyController extends Controller {

    private final Config config;

    @Inject
    public MyController(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```